# Помогите сделать выборку SELECT не хочет работать

Tags: php, html, sql

И так! Не могу заставить работать выборку.
Допустим, у меня есть 5 категорий с `id 1,2,3,4 и 5`.
И есть, например, товар который должен быть в двух категориях, например в 3 и 5.
Как я делаю логически: в товаре в базе сделал `category1` и `category2` куда и вписываю id нужных категорий. Выборку делаю так: `SELECT * FROM tovar WHERE category1 ='3' AND category2 ='5'`
Но ничего не работает. По отдельности работает, как только задаю на 2 категории, то не выводит ничего.

Comment: *в товаре в базе сделал category1 и category2* Почитайте о нормализации, а, может, и просто о базах данных, хоть что-нибудь...

Comment: Вместо `AND` поставьте `OR` для начала! Ну и про язык SQL тоже стоит почитать ) А если id у вас число, а вы ищете по строке, то могут быть непредсказуемые результаты

Answer (score 0):

`` SELECT * FROM `tovar` WHERE `category1` = 3 OR `category2` = 5 ``

Учитесь писать правильный ситаксис и делать декомпозицию. Вы хотите найти товара "И те И те" или "те ИЛИ те". Язык SQL довольно простой и понятный, но практикуйтесь больше